# Next auth v4 throws error access_token not present in TokenSet

Tags: reactjs, next.js, oauth-2.0, next-auth

When trying to sign in using auth0 with custom provider, the response object which is returned to next auth has key **accessToken** instead of **access_token**. So it is throwing error of access token not found.

But when I tried to check actual response it also has the required values under the key 'json'.
File in which above error is thrown is client.js from the library.
Please refer the attached screenshot.
[image]

So my question is, is there any way / config to ask library to get token using key as **accessToken** instead of **access_token**.

#### How to reproduce

Not sure about reproducing or forming the schema as per ours.
But in versions 3 and below next auth was reading token as accessToken and not access_token

Tried updating it with callbacks but this error is thrown before callbacks are called